# How to Select MYSQL datetime column to HTML input datetime

Tags: php, mysql

I have `$datetime` a value selected from MYSQL datetime column how to convert the format.

this php code doesn't work: `<input type="datetime" value=<?php echo '"'.$datetime.'"' ?> />`

Comment: look at php's datetime class.

Comment: I am asking that question because none of the bottom answer has worked  I did an echo $datetime; the result was '2013-03-19 14:00:00'. so the $datetime is right but whatever I do what I want to achieve doesn't work and none of the below answers has worked for me

Comment: @CBroe I am not looking for MYSQL DATE formatting. I am asking how to select it to HTML INPUT DATETIME, you just didn't read the question well.

Comment: No, you just did not understand the answer. You can have MySQL return you that date in the right formatting already, so you can pass it into the input value straight away. (But since I got the impression that you are not willing to read and learn something but just expect to get working code as answer, why bother anyway …)

Comment: @Pitchinnate I did read it, just everything did't work, and I can't find the answer anywhere

Comment: @CBroe I have showed you the result was '2013-03-19 14:00:00' from echo $datetime

Comment: What isn't working? You do realize that the input type 'datetime' is HTML5 and isn't currently supported by all browsers yet.

Comment: According to this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp the datetime input type is only valid in safari and opera at this point.

Comment: @Pitchinnate yes I know that infact I am using Google Chrome

Comment: Chrome doesn't support 'datetime', just 'date'.

Comment: @Pitchinnate I am using input type datetime-local

Comment: Also not supported by Chrome at least according to that site.

Comment: That isn't what you show in your question.

Comment: @Pitchinnate I used it in MYSQL insertion form and it is working correctly

Comment: @AhmedHossny hard to help you if you aren't copying and pasting your actual code. You say you are using datetime-local, but in your question you html code shows datetime. What is it really?

Comment: @Pitchinnate I am sorry for taking your time, thank you for all the help. I guess I have to figure it out on my own for now, really appreciate your help, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input type 'datetime' is HTML5 and only supported in Safari and Opera at this point. It is not going to work for any other browser.

Comment: In Chrome I have separate the input type Date and input type Time then  it worked. input datetime-local in Chrome Is visibly working but not fully working, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 5.3 this is very easy:

$date = new DateTime($datetime);

echo $date->format('needful_fromat_here');

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the format in PHP using a combination of [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
<?php echo '"' . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($datetime)) . '"' ?>
```

You could also format it in MySQL instead with [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
DATE_FORMAT(datetimeCol, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to change the format. First is in the query it self see [mysql date time format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%W %M %Y');

//'Sunday October 2009'
```

another option is to do it in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($datetime));

// default SQL format, but you get the idea how to change it
// 2012-01-01 10:15:59
```